# Determining endpoint from a WSDL file

Tags: xml, soap, wsdl, soapui

I'm new to web services and have been tasked with trying to write some packages in PL/SQL that make requests to an external web service to allow customers to view their current support tickets and the status of where we are at in terms of supporting the ticket. I have been given the WSDL location for the service I am trying to use and I have used SOAPUI to inspect the WSDL to form some requests. However, when I try and run a login request it always fails (I think because the endpoint defined in SOAP UI in incorrect.

Here is the WSDL file I am trying to use:
http://www.visionproject.se/api/docs/service.wsdl

And the API for the service:
http://www.visionproject.se/api/docs/soap_service_VisionProjectWebServiceService.html#login2

And here is the request I am trying to form (shown below). Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why this is failing? I believe it may be to do with the endpoint at the top but I'm not sure.

As I said, I'm new to web services and indeed PL/SQL (I'm from a PHP background and have never done this stuff before) so I apologise if I haven't included enough information.

[image: WSDL Usage]

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"     xmlns:vis="http://www.visionproject.se/service/VisionProjectService-v2">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <vis:login2>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <username>?</username>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <password>?</password>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <visionProjectVersion>?</visionProjectVersion>
      </vis:login2>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Why the hell has this been down-voted?

Comment: Documentation states `this method [login2] can only be used on installed version. use loginwithapikeyv2 for the hosted version`. Do you have a hosted or installed version ? Maybe you've chosen the wrong api. Also, you probably have to provide actual username and password values in place of the '?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some sample test clients available in the API documentation link you have provided. These make use of the following endpoint URL:

`http://www.visionproject.se/service/VisionProject-v2/VisionProjectWebServiceService`

When pasting this to a browser it returns "Invalid SOAP request" so it seems as if there is a service running on this URL.

Give this a try.

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly. Sorry if it's a really simple question but there is little to no documentation that is written correctly online regarding this topic and I've never had to use it before.

Answer (score 2):

The endpoint looks like it's probably correct. A WSDL can have a "suggested" endpoint, but isn't guaranteed to be the actual endpoint.  i.e. at the bottom of your WSDL there's an entry for:   (StackOverflow didn't like me posting the actual URL, as it contains localhost and is clearly bogus.)

Your request is likely failing because you haven't replaced the ? placeholders with actual values.
Replace those and send it again.

Comment: I already tried doing that and it doesn't work.